# mod_Rewrite: Allow only one IP and redirect the rest to a certain error url?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, ip

I got a code that will match a certain block of IP and redirect them to another page.

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.10\..*
RewriteRule ^/support http://www.yahoo.com/gone [R,NE,NC]
```

However, how would I reverse this? to only allow one IP and redirect the rest to a certain url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^!192\.168\.10\..*
RewriteRule ^/support http://www.yahoo.com/gone [R,NE,NC]
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be?
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.168\.10\..*